# Google Cloud message register when lost connection then the app crash

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM plugin for Unity. I register it with dynamic senderIDs. But if i lost connection while registering, the app crashes.

The error log is :

```
W/System.err( 4993): java.lang.IllegalStateException: sender id not set on constructor
W/System.err( 4993):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.getSenderIds(GCMBaseIntentService.java:125)
W/System.err( 4993):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:237)
W/System.err( 4993):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
W/System.err( 4993):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 4993):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/System.err( 4993):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-2]
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): Process: ba.lum.tribalrivals.arabic, PID: 4993
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [IntentService[GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-2]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): Unity version     : 4.6.7f1
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): Device model      : samsung SM-N910C
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): Device fingerprint: samsung/treltexx/trelte:5.0.1/LRX22C/N910CXXU1BOE1:user/release-keys
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): 
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: sender id not set on constructor
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.getSenderIds(GCMBaseIntentService.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4993):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I found out that the reason is from this code inside gcm.jar (plugin library):

```
protected String[] getSenderIds(Context context)
  {
    if (this.mSenderIds == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("sender id not set on constructor");
    }
    return this.mSenderIds;
  }
```

Can anyone know how to fix this problem ? Should i change the code inside plugin ? And how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the GCM plugin for Unity. However, this clearly indicates that your app cannot find the sender ID (project number) of the project that you created on the Google developers console. Find that, and add it to the mSenderIds array. It looks like you can do so in the constructor when you create an instance of that class.